# How to add html tag and page number automatically using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using a slideshow that automatically generates button links for every slide that is added to it.  I needed the code to also add (slide number) into each button and I was wondering how I would be able to do this

Comment: but seriously if you want good answers you need to show some html or javascript and give a better description of your problem other than "i need to add a slide number".

Answer (score 0):

Some [slideshow](http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/jquery-image-galleries/) plugins can do it, you'll just have to select one!